# Eliminate horizontal scroll of a relative positioned div

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to keep a div (id='fixedDiv') at the top of the window while the user scrolls up and down the webpage. The page has another much taller div (id='tallDiv'). I want the user to scroll the page up and down to see the content of tallDiv, and fixedDiv to always be displayed at the top of the window during the scrolling.

The problem is if the user does a horizontal scroll, tallDiv appears to move left or right, while fixedDiv stays put. My question is how do I keep tallDiv from "moving?"

I tried to detect a horizontal scroll in the $(window).scroll event by keeping track of $(document).scrollLeft() and setting  tallDiv's position to 'fixed' during a horizontal scroll. I then use a timer to set tallDiv's position back to 'relative' But that gets ugly.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can accomplish what I want? My code follows:

```js
function SetScrollable() {
  $('#tallDiv').css('position', 'relative');
}

var lastScrollLeft;

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
  // what the y position of the scroll is
  var documentScrollLeft = $(document).scrollLeft();
  if (lastScrollLeft != documentScrollLeft) {
    lastScrollLeft = documentScrollLeft;
    $('#tallDiv').css('position', 'fixed');
    setTimeout('SetScrollable()', 500);
  }
  else {
    $('#tallDiv').css('position', 'relative');
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div id="fixedDiv" style="position:absolute;background-color:yellow; height:40px; width:40px;" >
  </div>

  <div id="tallDiv" style="position:relative; left:300px; top:0px; background-color:green; height:400px; width:40px;" >
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you position the tallDiv absolute and right aligned? (ex:position absolute; right: 100px;)